# immune system - how does adaptive work without innate?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, proteins, immunology, virology

The way I understood immune system is that:

- phagocytes detect viruses and present it on their surface and become antigen presenting cells.
- Then, T-helper cells try to bind to these phagocytes that have antigen on their surface and found, T-helper cells become effector T-helper cells which then cause the activation of B-cell.

Question 1: If phagocytes can't detect virus, that means T-helper cells wouldn't be activated(there would be no process of cytokines) and if no cytokines, B-cell activation wouldn't happen. and if no B-cell activation, no antibodies releasing. So This means unless phagocytes detect the virus, B-cell activation doesn't happen, but this would be too bad, because if B-cell activation depend on the phagocytes finding the virus, this means if innate immune response fails, adaptive also fails. I'm wondering when would still B-cell be activated even without phagocytes finding the virus in the first place ?
otherwise, B-cell always depending on phagocytes would be too bad...

Question 2: Am I right that B-cells can detect/identify the virus that couldn't have been identified by the phagocytes ? I think so, because phagocytes have general PRR which sometimes might be unable to detect, but B-cells have more combinations of variable portion proteins that could detect more stuff ?

Comment: B cells can be phagocytic, and can present antigen to T cells both via MHC-I and MHC-II pathways. Different PRRs can be found in many cell types so they can detect infection and signal that to the immune system. You might be interested in the topic of [immune evasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigenic_escape).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But am I right about my 2nd question ?